# How can I use the following events/delegates, written in C#, in VB.NET?

Tags: c#, vb.net, events, delegates, apns-sharp

I'm using JdSoft's APNS-Sharp library in my ASP.NET web app. The library is written in C#, and makes extensive use of Delegate Functions and Events for threading purposes. My application is written in VB.NET, and I'm a little confused on about how to translate the following sample code (C#):

```
....
//Wireup the events
service.Error += new FeedbackService.OnError(service_Error);
....
}

static void service_Error(object sender, Exception ex)
{
Console.WriteLine(...);
}
```

Here are the relevant members of the FeedbackService class:

```
public delegate void OnError(object sender, Exception ex);
public event OnError Error;
```

Basically, I'm trying to figure out how to attach a function (like service_Error) to an event (like Error) in VB.NET. I'm unclear on what the += syntax means in this context, and VisualStudio says that the 'Error' event cannot be accessed directly by my VB.NET code for some reason.

Comment: Just subscribe to the event like you normally would.  You should post what you attempted.

Comment: To be honest, I've actually never worked with threads in ASP.NET. My first attempts/research efforts were directed at delegate methods like  'combine' and 'adddelegate.' I was definitely going down the wrong road there.

Comment: You should research how to register an event within an ASP.NET application.  One major difference is you have to worry about the session and any other unique problems to a ASP.NET page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `+=` operator is basically subscribing the `FeedbackService.OnError` function to the `Error` invocation list. So when the `Error` event is raised, the `OnError` method is invoked.

To translate the above code to VB.NET, it would look something like:

```
// define delelgate/event
Public Delegate Sub OnError(sender As Object, ex As Exception)
Public Event OnError Error

// attach method to event
AddHandler service.Error, service_Error
```

See [How to: Raise and Consume Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9aackb16.aspx) for some examples in VB.NET.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get the event wired up using something like AddHandler service.Error, AddressOf service_Error

Answer (score 2):

```
AddHandler service.Error, service_Error
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure on the VB implementation I'm afraid, but the += syntax in C# with respect to delegates, adds a method to the delegates list of methods (invocation list)